# Source for Rebbi Nachman's statement about the Tanaaim and Amoraim

Tags: sources-mekorot, zohar, breslov

Towards the end of torah 10 (section 1) in likutei moharan Rebbi Nachman makes a statement pairing the tanaaim with the legs and amoraim with the hands, "תַּנָּאִים בַּשּׁוֹקַיִן וְאָמוֹרָאִים בַּיָּדַיִן" which he says is based on the zohar. Where is this found in the zohar?

Comment: I did a quick Google, Bar Ilan, and Otzar Hahochma search on the phrase, and no luck and tried some permutations of the phrase as well, no luck on any words close to it, but in the ליקוטי מוהר"ן ע"פ שלום מלכות the footnote on that statement has the following sources:  עיין זוהר ח"ב רנח. ובתקו"ז תיקון כא דף מג: ועי' בקה"י ערך אמוראים

Comment: I looked up the sources, and it doesn't have the exact phrase, but some phrases similar to it, the sources are a little off in the footnote, the first should be רנז (both amudim) and the second in some editions is on מד. here is the link for the last source: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44143&st=&pgnum=28

Comment: It should be noted that R. Nachman himself and R. Nassan are quoted as saying his sources are "Asmachtos"...

Comment: See Sichos HaRan 202 and 210; Chayei Moharan (Rosenfeld)- Shivchei Moharan- Gedulas Hasagaso 47; Maalas Toraso 21 and 46; also brought at the end of some eds. of Likutei Moharan as Sichos MiMaalas Toraso (Schick) 25 and 27 or (Meshech HaNachal) 22 depending on the many eds.... ; Chayei Moharan (Meshech HaNachal)15, 287,  361; CM-SM (Keren Hadpasah Y-m) GH 47 and MT 22; Sefer HaMiddos, Hakdamah III of R. Nassan, Chidushin D'Oraysa II 2,  Mammon II 29; SHM (Toras HaNetzach) All Hakdamos, CDO there, Mammon II 5; See also Mayim Chayim (Tunik) p 268-272

Answer (score 1):

In the *Keren R' Yisrael Dov Odesser* printing of the *Likutei moHaran* it is sourced as somewhere in the *Tikkunei Zohar* but I didn't understand precisely where it could be found. If I read it correctly it says that it's in an appendix found in the *tikkunim* on Daf 10. That's the best I have at this time, and will update if I find more information.